# Could not connect hive mysql metastore using spark-submit

Tags: mysql, hive, spark-submit

when i tried to connect Hive Mysql metastore throws error as connection refused. Given below the details from pom.xml, hive-site.xml and code

```
spark-submit --class org.com.IoTLogAnalytics.iot_fetch_ad --master yarn
--deploy-mode client --files file:///opt/spark/conf/hive-site.xml /opt/script/jar/com.IoTLogAnalytics-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar



package org.com.IoTLogAnalytics

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.io.File

//import java.util.Properties


object iot_fetch_ad {

  def main(args:Array[String])
  {

//   val sconf = new SparkConf()
//                    .setAppName("IoTAnalytics")
//   //                 .setMaster("local")
//                    .set("Spark.executor.memory","1g")

//  val sc = new SparkContext(sconf)
  //val sqlc = new SqlContext(sconf)
  val table = "iotlog_tbl"


  //val url = "jdbc:mysql://172.25.140.126:3306"  
  //val properties = new Properties()
  //properties.put("user","root")
  //properties.put("password","Password_123")

  //val warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath  
  val warehouseLocation = "hdfs://172.25.140.125:8020/user/hive/warehouse"
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
                        .master("yarn")
                        .appName("iotla")
                        //.config("spark.yarn.jars","hdfs//172.25.140.125:8020/tmp/*.jar")
                        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
                        .config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://cch1wpsteris01:9083")
                        .enableHiveSupport()
                        .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    import spark.sql

  //val mysqlDF = spark.read.jdbc(url, table, properties)

    spark.sqlContext.sql("show databases").show();
    spark.sqlContext.sql("show tables").show();

    spark.sqlContext.sql("use sterisdb")
    val getLog = spark.sqlContext.sql("select * from sterisdb.iotlog_tbl")
    getLog.show()

}
}

19/06/02 00:14:24 INFO hive.HiveUtils: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 1.2.1 using Spark classes.
19/06/02 00:14:24 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://cch1wpsteris01:9083
19/06/02 00:14:24 WARN hive.metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
19/06/02 00:14:24 INFO hive.metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
19/06/02 00:14:25 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://cch1wpsteris01:9083
19/06/02 00:14:25 WARN hive.metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
19/06/02 00:14:25 INFO hive.metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
19/06/02 00:14:26 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://cch1wpsteris01:9083
19/06/02 00:14:26 WARN hive.metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
19/06/02 00:14:26 INFO hive.metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
19/06/02 00:14:27 WARN metadata.Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:384)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listDatabases(SessionCatalog.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand.run(databases.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
        at org.com.IoTLogAnalytics.iot_fetch_ad$.main(iot_fetch_ad.scala:47)
        at org.com.IoTLogAnalytics.iot_fetch_ad.main(iot_fetch_ad.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        ... 65 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:384)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listDatabases(SessionCatalog.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand.run(databases.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
        at org.com.IoTLogAnalytics.iot_fetch_ad$.main(iot_fetch_ad.scala:47)
        at org.com.IoTLogAnalytics.iot_fetch_ad.main(iot_fetch_ad.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221)
        ... 73 more
)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:466)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        ... 70 more
19/06/02 00:14:27 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://cch1wpsteris01:9083
19/06/02 00:14:27 WARN hive.metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
19/06/02 00:14:27 INFO hive.metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
19/06/02 00:14:28 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://cch1wpsteris01:9083
19/06/02 00:14:28 WARN hive.metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
19/06/02 00:14:28 INFO hive.metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
19/06/02 00:14:29 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://cch1wpsteris01:9083
19/06/02 00:14:29 WARN hive.metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
19/06/02 00:14:29 INFO hive.metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listDatabases(SessionCatalog.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand.run(databases.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
        at org.com.IoTLogAnalytics.iot_fetch_ad$.main(iot_fetch_ad.scala:47)
        at org.com.IoTLogAnalytics.iot_fetch_ad.main(iot_fetch_ad.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstruct
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 possible reasons:

1. It looks like your hive metastore has been locked and spark is unable to access. You need to remove the lock files from the metastore.

   ```
   rm metastore_db/*.lck
   ```
2. Also you need to check if the metastore server is up and running. Try the below code:

   ```
   ps -ef | grep metastore
   ```

If not, can you try looking into the log:  /var/log/hive/hivemetastore.log

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Issues is not around the locking ... I missed to put dependencies for thrift server. It is working fine now.  Thank you anyway